# Alfresco: outgoing mail properties are read but ignored

Tags: email, alfresco

I've an Alfresco community 7.4.1 installed on a local server, using the distribuzion zip files. Alfresco is working correctly. This instance was migrated from Alfresco 5, to 6, and finally to 7. The migration apparently went well, in all parts.

I've have a problem when I try to configure outgoing email:
Even if I change the properties in my alfresco-global.properties files under `/tomcat/shared/classes`, and those modification are apparently taken up (as shown in the OOTB console page as you can see from the screenshot)

[image]

then other configuration are used when sending the emails, some older configurations of that server.

Can someone explaim me why is this happening and where I should modify those parameters? Do they exists also in the database?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have some custom code that have hardcoded some of these values?

Comment: I use the default sendEmail action, which uses the default outbound Alfresco configuration. So no, I'm sure I've no custom configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution.
The problem was in an additional amp module, OOTBee Support Tools version 1.2.1.0 which had a "bug" on the [Persistent-Subsystem-Configuration](https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools/wiki/Persistent-Subsystem-Configuration) functionality.

This amp is maintained by the community and I cannot say for sure but maybe that bug was created when the module was updated (1.0.0 --> 1.1.0 --> 1.2.1.0), along with the Alfresco system (it went from 5.2---> 6.2 --> 7.4.1)

The detailed explaination is the following:
The previous SMTP configurations were saved in the database, by this module, and never updated, even if the system was rebooted multiple times. Those DB config were always used to send the email.
I had to manually revert the persistence module saved proeperties using the [Subsystems-Plugin-Commands](https://github.com/OrderOfTheBee/ootbee-support-tools/wiki/Command%20Console#Subsystems-Plugin-Commands) tool.